# Cannot set Cherokee FastCGI to Mono

Tags: fastcgi, cherokee

I used this as information source:

```
/usr/bin/fastcgi-mono-server2 --socket=tcp --address=127.0.0.1 --port=39893 --applications=/:/var/www
```

Put extension to *.aspx and made one index.aspx file in /var/www

But when pointed it, see only text of it.